# Typecast all arguments in a variadic macro

Tags: c, arguments, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

I want to use `sscanf` to parse a long string ..
The data to be parsed will be stored in a struct whose members are all of the type `time_t`.
Unfortunately, there isn't any format string to mark a `time_t` so I'm just going to typecast all `time_t *` arguments as `unsigned long long *`, and because its a very long string with lots of arguments, typecasting each argument one by one will only mess my editor screen ..

So, I created a macro to simplify this:

```
#define typecast(type, ...) (type) __VA_ARGS__
```

And I invoked it like this:

```
sscanf(string, PARSE_STRING,
    typecast(unsigned long long *, /* my arguments */));
```

I though this would expand to:

```
sscanf(string, PARSE_STRING,
    (unsigned long long *) /* arg1 */, (unsigned long long *) /* arg2 */, /* and so on */);
```

But after inspecting with `gcc -E`, I found it expanded to this:

```
sscanf(string, PARSE_STRING,
    (unsigned long long *) /* arg1 */, /* arg2 */, /* and so on */));
```

How can I achieve my desired expansion functionality using variadic functions ?

Comment: You might get some inspiration [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26582302/a-group-of-variadic-macros/26582594#26582594).

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872220/) also has some relevant answers.

Comment: Note that `time_t` is normally an signed integer type.  If you're scanning, you have to be sure that the type is compatible with `time_t` — it is somewhat platform specific.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I didn't know `time_t` was signed because time is either zero or positive, but anyway, I'm certain that the data I'm reading will never have negative values.

Comment: Classically, time 0 is 1970-01-01 00:00:00 Z (or +00:00).  The `mktime()` function returns `(time_t)-1` on error.  With a 32-bit signed type (`long` on older 32-bit systems), the range of representable times is from 1901-12-13 (0x80000000) to 2038-01-18 (0x7FFFFFFF) roughly.  That's why you'll sometimes see comments about the Y2038 crisis; 32-bit signed `time_t` will rollover then.  Most systems now use 64-bit `time_t` to avoid that problem (and the Y10K problem, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use boost

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/punctuation/comma_if.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each_i.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/transform.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/variadic/to_seq.hpp>

#define CAMMA(r, data, i, elem) BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(i)elem
#define CAST(r, data, elem) (data)elem
#define typecast(type, ...) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(CAMMA, , BOOST_PP_SEQ_TRANSFORM(CAST, type, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__)))
```

Comment: @AmrAyman `boost/preprocessor`  can also be used in C. (because only use preprocessor)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen C preprocessor code looping over arguments of variadic macros and I wouldn't want it in my code. However, in your case, you can take the following solution. I am presenting macros which work for up to 4 arguments, you will surely be able to extend it to any constant.

```
#define typecast4(type, a1, a2, a3, a4, ...) ((type)a1), ((type)a2), ((type)a3), ((type)a4)
#define typecast(type, ...) typecast4(type, __VA_ARGS__, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

This particular solution generates 4 arguments always. Note that, in your case, this does not matter  because scanf accepts and safely ignores any arguments beyond the entered format. So, the following code compiles:

```
int main() {
  time_t x,y;
  scanf("%lld, %lld", typecast(long long *, &x, &y));
  ...
}
```

However, I am worrying about the cast from `time_t *` to `long long *`. It is written nowhere that `time_t` must be represented by `long long`. If it is represented by `int` on some platform the previous code will be buggy. The correct way to scan your values would be something like:

```
int main() {
  time_t x,y;
  long long lx, ly;
  scanf("%lld, %lld", &lx, &ly);
  x = lx;
  y = ly;
  ...
}
```

which is more correct and does not require any variadic macro.